# fstab cifs mount stopped working in Ubuntu 22.04 LTS “Jammy Jellyfish” : bad option

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs

After installing Ubuntu 22.04 LTS “Jammy Jellyfish”, I noticed that the network drives listed in my Favourites no longer work.

When I tried "sudo mount -a" in terminal - I got error messages. I found some hints that my "vers=1.0" should be modified. I corrected all 3 entries in /etc/fstab. I still get error messages.   Please help!

Here is the version which worked in Ubuntu 18 :

```
//192.168.0.254/Disque\040dur /media/freebox  cifs  guest,vers=1.0,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0  
//192.168.0.254/Samsung_T5 /media/samsung_t5  cifs  guest,vers=1.0,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0  
//192.168.0.254/VERBATIM2 /media/verbatim2  cifs  guest,vers=1.0,uid=1000,iocharset=utf8  0  0
```

After I changed vers=1.0 to vers=2.0, I still get the following error for each network drive:
**mount: /media/freebox: bad option; for several filesystems (e.g. nfs, cifs) you might need a /sbin/mount. helper program**.

I have been carefully reading [manpages for mount.cifs](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/jammy/en/man8/mount.cifs.8.html) for Ubuntu 22.04 but I do not understand what I should change.

Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like you're missing cifs-utils so just run

```
sudo apt install -y cifs-utils
```

Answer (score 1):

To add cifs-utils was not enough for me, i needed :

```
sudo apt install cifs-utils nfs-common
```

I assume cifs-utils was enough for jjmeric, but the error message say both cifs and nfs.